# composer install private repository in custom directory

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-submodules, composer-php

I am trying to install my private repository using `composer` and i have this code for my bitbucket repository which is being cloned inside `vendor/paladinstha/core`

```
"repositories": [
    "type": "package",
    "package": {
      "name": "paladinstha/core",
      "version": "dev-master",
      "source": {
        "url": "git@bitbucket.org:paladinstha/core.git",
        "type": "git",
        "reference": "origin/master"
      },
      "autoload": {
        "psr-4": { "": "src/" }
      }
    }
  }
],
```

the folder structure now is:

```
|-Modules
|-vendor
  |-paladinstha
    |-core
```

but i intend to clone it inside `Modules` directory. I have also tried to install in custom path using this composer [docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/how-do-i-install-a-package-to-a-custom-path-for-my-framework.md)

I have set like this in my `composer.json` file.

```
"extra": {
  "installer-paths": {
    "Modules/Core": ["paladinstha/core"]
  }
},
```

It is being cloned to `vendor` directory. What am i doing wrong? Could any one put a light on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot clone inside that directory. Composer is meant to download and manage packages that depends one on the others.
They are all downloaded into the vendor flder, also if they are private repositories.
Then, using namespaces you can use them in you project.

Anyway you can specify the path, yes, but **ever into the `vendor` directory, not outside of it.**

Only if you are developing a package for a specific supported package type you can specify a directory outside the `vendor` folder.

Here there is [the list](https://github.com/composer/installers#current-supported-types) of supported packages.

As [stated](https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/how-do-i-install-a-package-to-a-custom-path-for-my-framework.md) in the documentation:

> simply require composer/installers and set the **appropriate type**. This is common if your package is intended for a specific framework such as CakePHP, Drupal or WordPress.